# Timing issues with PrintStreams

Tags: java, eclipse, printstream

I'm using eclipse IDE, and sometimes, depending on the code, System.err output is printed before than System.out's. For instance:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {    
        System.out.println("Regular text"); //1
        System.err.println("Error text"); //2           
    }
```

With that code, everything is fine. 2 is printed after 1. However, adding some extra system.out sentences reverses the order:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {    
        System.out.println("Regular text"); //1
        System.err.println("Error text"); //2

        //Additional printing stuff
        for(String s = "a";s.length() < 200; s = s.concat("" + (char)(s.charAt(s.length()-1)+ 1))){
            System.out.println(s);
        }

    }
```

1 is printed after 2.

How is this possible?

Comment: A quick google search shows this identical topic on SO.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4255743/how-to-keep-sysout-and-syserr-streams-from-intermixing

Comment: @Joseph I searched in SO before asking, no result. Your googling skills are quite remarkable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On some OSes (*nix in particular), the standard output stream is buffered -- that is, whatever gets sent to it might sit around a bit before being sent to the terminal/screen.  Standard error, however, often is *not* buffered, or is auto-flushed after each output.

`System.out` and `System.err` are just Java's objects to represent those two streams, and thus, tend to behave as they would on the host platform.  But i'm not aware of anything that specifically says they have to.

Comment: So in your opinion this behaviour depends on the JVM implementation?

Comment: Yes.  And/or the compiler and/or C(++)? runtime used to build it.  And/or the OS.  And/or the phase of the moon.  Don't rely on any particular synchronization between the two streams unless you flush them yourself.  I'm only saying what i've seen; other OSes, VMs, etc *will* behave differently when you can least afford for them to.

Comment: I just checked the System class source code. There are a couple of methods `private static native void setErr0(PrintStream err);` and `private static native void setOut0(PrintStream out);`. However, at some point, both streams are decorated with buffers like this: `setErr0(new PrintStream(new BufferedOutputStream(fdErr, 128), true));` (line 1115).

Comment: `System.out` is buffered?  Eww.  :P  Either way, the JVM interacts with the C runtime its compiler told it to link against, which interacts with the OS, which interacts with the console.  If both streams are closed at the same time, it's up to one (or all) of those layers to decide which bunch of bytes is first in line to get printed.  The only real way to say "this goes first" is to flush the streams yourself.  Or, if you need stuff printed in order, you could pick one stream and print to it.  :)  The two streams are logically separate, and really should not need to be synchronized anyway.

Comment: It's a Perl-style regular expression/statement.  It means "replace .out with .err" (referring to the comment right before it).

Answer (score 2):

`stderr` and `stdout` are 2 different streams, and normally will be printed when flushed. I would expect some buffering to take place and this would affect flushing. Consequently the quantity of data in each stream will affect the flushing and the output.

Comment: All right, so to write output in order, I can write a class `AutoFlushedOutput` that flushes the streams after each print statement, and even then it is not guaranteed to work.

Answer (score 0):

They are separate streams each with their own buffers. You write to a stream which is then "copied" or written out to the console.

You should find that calling

```
System.out.flush()
System.err.flush()
```

will flush the streams to the actual device (the Eclipse console) and bring some semblance of order.

Comment: I tried flushing both streams before lines 1 and 2, and the result is the same.

Comment: You want to flush *after*, not before.  Flushing sends what's still buffered in the streams (which is your output) out to the underlying whatsit.  You need that if you want to synchronize the two streams.

Comment: You're right. That'll flush the Java buffers but not any underlying system buffers or resources. Its been a while since I looked at the Eclipse Console code but remember Eclipse itself is consuming the System.err/out and redirecting them to its own GUI. How and when it does this complicates matters as well.

Comment: So, in Eclipse IDE you have this code http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/Java-Document/IDE-Eclipse/ui/org/eclipse/ui/console/IOConsoleOutputStream.java.htm reading the stream and writing it to the Console View.