# JUnit tearDown() finishes executing before my tests finish (using custom runner)

Tags: java, multithreading, junit, jira-rest-java-api

JUnit @AfterClass methods finish executing before my @Tests (custom runner)

I'm trying to make my own JUnit test runner. I want to do stuff every time a method annotated by @AfterClass is executed. According to the JUnit documentation, @AfterClass methods should start executing after all the tests have ran.

I have looked through google, peroused the JUnit documentation thoroughly, read about
JUnit execution order on StackOverflow, etc. but I can't seem to find any other examples of this happening (probably a threading issue). I found an example Spring using their own runner at [SpringJUnit4ClassRunner JavaDoc](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.springframework/spring-test/3.0.0.RELEASE/org/springframework/test/context/junit4/SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java) but it hasn't helped me solve the problem.

```
public class CustomRunner extends BlockJUnit4ClassRunner {

    public CustomRunner (Class<?> klass) throws InitializationError {
        super(klass);
    }

    @Override
    protected Statement withAfterClasses(Statement statement) {
        Statement s = super.withAfterClasses(statement);
        System.out.println("tearDown() executed!");
        return s;
    }
}
```

Without the CustomRunner:

```
public class TestBugReporter0 {

    @Before
    public void setUp() {}

    @Test
    public void testAssertionFailure() {
        assertEquals(3, 2);
    }

    @AfterClass
    public static void tearDown() {
        System.out.println("tearDown() executed!");
    }
}
```

With the CustomRunner:

```
@RunWith(CustomRunner.class)
public class TestBugReporter1 {

    @Before
    public void setUp() {}

    @Test
    public void testAssertionFailure() {
        assertEquals(3, 2);
    }

    @AfterClass
    public static void tearDown() {}
}
```

TestBugReporter0 *always* prints out the following:

```
setUp() executed!
java.lang.AssertionError: Expected :3, Actual :2
tearDown() executed!
```

However, TestBugReporter1 isn't deterministic. After 20 runs, I always got one of the following three.

```
tearDown() executed!
setUp() executed!
java.lang.AssertionError: Expected :3, Actual :2

java.lang.AssertionError: Expected :3, Actual :2
tearDown() executed!
setUp() executed!

setUp() executed!
java.lang.AssertionError: Expected :3, Actual :2
tearDown() executed!
```

I think this is a threading issue because:

1. The results are non-deterministic.
2. The methods execute out of order.

If I add a Thread.sleep(3000) to my withAfterClasses() method in CustomRunner, I always get the first of the three possibilities. I could probably force any of the three possibilities with different sleeps, for example, putting one in the tearDown() itself would force number three. However, Thread.sleep() isn't a real solution.

Would making the entire TestBugReporter1 methods execute deterministically in the right order? If so, how would I do that? And please speak up if you know a better solution than putting everything on one thread! :)

Thanks in advance your help and for not copy-pasting links without explaining what they mean. My multithreading background is very limited so I may not understand documentation without context.

Note: TestNG has a single-threaded config but our existing test suite is in pure JUnit so it's not an option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The method `withAfterClasses` (and any of the other methods starting with `with`) *do not execute anything* from your test class. Rather, they build up a chain of `Statement` objects that represent what is going to be executed later.

`Statement`:

> Represents one or more actions to be taken at runtime in the course of
>   running a JUnit test suite.

Have a look at the class `RunAfters`, which is a subclass of `Statement` and is returned by the default implementation of `withAfterClasses`.

It seems like JUnit can request this `Statement` at differing times during the lifecycle of your test class; however you shouldn't care about that - just return an instance `Statement`. You can see this as a command pattern.

**Update**

The standard `RunAfters` implementation makes it hard to subclass and to do something just before it invokes the `@AfterClass` or just after the `@AfterClass` methods, so my earlier suggestions isn't as easy to implement.

Here's how you can do it.

*CustomRunner*:

```
public class CustomRunner extends BlockJUnit4ClassRunner {
    public CustomRunner(Class<?> klass) throws InitializationError {
        super(klass);
    }

    @Override
    protected Statement withAfterClasses(Statement statement) {
        List<FrameworkMethod> afters = getTestClass().getAnnotatedMethods(AfterClass.class);
        statement = new CustomRunAfters(statement, afters, null);
        return statement;
    }
}
```

*CustomRunAfters*:

```
public class CustomRunAfters extends Statement {

    private final Statement fNext;

    private final Object fTarget;

    private final List<FrameworkMethod> fAfters;

    public CustomRunAfters(Statement next, List<FrameworkMethod> afters, Object target) {
        fNext = next;
        fAfters = afters;
        fTarget = target;
    }

    @Override
    public void evaluate() throws Throwable {
        List<Throwable> fErrors = new ArrayList<Throwable>();
        fErrors.clear();
        try {
            fNext.evaluate();
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            fErrors.add(e);
        } finally {
            beforeRunAfters();
            for (FrameworkMethod each : fAfters) {
                try {
                    each.invokeExplosively(fTarget);
                } catch (Throwable e) {
                    fErrors.add(e);
                }
            }
            afterRunAfters();
        }
        if (fErrors.isEmpty())
            return;
        if (fErrors.size() == 1)
            throw fErrors.get(0);
        throw new MultipleFailureException(fErrors);
    }

    private void afterRunAfters() {
        System.err.println("After running @AfterClass methods");
    }

    private void beforeRunAfters() {
        System.err.println("Before running @AfterClass methods");
    }
}
```

In the above code, you can do your custom actions in the `beforeRunAfters` and `afterRunAfters` methods.

*Note*: above snippets contain modified source code from JUnit 4.5. Insofar this is necessary, I hereby license my modifications under the same license as JUnit (Eclipse public license) etc.

Comment: I don't think that is the problem in this case since the output is not deterministic.

Comment: Why don't you try ? JUnit is free to call `withAfterClasses` at any point in time that it likes, because it is not actually executing any code; rather it is building up a declarative chain of actions to be performed later.

Comment: Yes, you are right about that. However, the code snippets are not consistent. The class TestBugReporter0 contains the output in the @AfterMethod as well as the method in the CustomRunner.

Comment: Yeah you're right, if he printed everything on System.err, then the order he sees would be: `setUp`, `tearDown`, *error* consistently. The problem is a combination of your and my answer.

Comment: Thanks guys, I'm trying this out right now. I originally had a static int class member in my TestBugReporter, which I incremented by 1 in each failed test case. I set a debug point on my tearDown and did something with the int and it was always 0.

Comment: I've posted code in the answer the shows how you can create your own Statement implementation to do this.

Answer (score 2):

The processing is done in the correct order.

The problem is the output.
Your output is written on System.out while the assertion error is printed using System.err.

Their output is not necessarily in the correct order.

See also

- https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/161194/why-is-using-system-out-println-so-bad
- [How to keep sysout and syserr streams from intermixing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4255743/how-to-keep-sysout-and-syserr-streams-from-intermixing)